# is it possible to get a user id from a username on telegram?

Tags: python, telegram

I'm trying to create moderation commands for the telegram bot.
Currently to ban a user I reply to his message with a command, obtaining the user's id from the message.
This is all inconvenient, I'd prefer the command to be structured like this:

```
/warn <username>.
```

I couldn't find any way to get the user id from the username.
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your bot can accept forwarded message. And parse user_id from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it using bot api - you shall use tdlib or account api except (with real telegram account with phone number).
But I see better option - as your bot exists in a group and you need only to ban users within the group, you can just store pairs username-id all the time from message updates you got by bot api. So then you check the username in your database and that's it